# PsExec error - "Couldn't install PSEXESVC service: Access is denied

Tags: windows-10, powershell, administrator, psexec

I've done a lot of research into this problem and still haven't found a solution. I wrote a powershell script that uses psexec to activate another one on a file share using a p2p network. I keep getting the above error. Here is my script:

```
$clients = get-content $PSScriptRoot\Clients.txt
foreach ($comp in $clients)
{
PsExec.exe -s -i -d \\$comp Powershell \\PATH_TO_FILESHARE\script.ps1
}
```

Answers I've tried:

- Removing the `-i` switch.
- Disabling UAC.
- Disabling Windows Firewall.
- Adding the `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` (set to 1) in the registry for each target.
- Swapping out the `-s` switch for `-u/-p` switches.
- Adding the `-h` switch.

Comment: `get-executionpolicy` returns what?

Comment: set to unrestricted.

Comment: Is Remote Execution enabled on the clients?

Comment: Execution policy was set to unrestricted on clients as well while testing

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I've found the answer. There is a GPO on the domain that needs to be added. Computer Config > Windows settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment: Make sure "allow log on locally" and "allow log on through remote desktop services" both are enabled with your admin account listed. Once I did that, all PowerShell scripts on a shared folder I had could be successfully executed on all systems with PSExec.

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: I don't even find a "Computer Config". Windows offers "Computer Management", "Windows Settings" and "System Configuration" - but there is no "Computer Config" with a subitem "Security Settings". I vote it down until the description will be improved! What about a screenshot?